# ES6/Typescript: Filtering array of objects based on items in other arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, which describes a group of chart types. Each one is of the format

```
{
  name: 'Donut Chart',
  category: ['comparisons'],
  subcategory: ['proportions']
},
```

You can see that each chart has an array of categories and subcategories it can match.

I have 2 sets of checkboxes, "categories" and "subcategories". Clicking one of these checkboxes adds the selected category to an array of `selectedCategories` and displays a list of subcategories, with their own checkboxes.

When a subcategory is chosen, as above, this adds the chosen subcategory to an array `selectedSubcategories`.

At this point, I'd like to display a list of the chart types which match the chosen categories (in the array `selectedCategories`) and subcategories (in the array `selectedSubcategories`).

I've created this (working) logic to display the checkboxes and add/remove items from the 2 arrays, but I am unclear how to create a filter for `chartsToDisplay`, which will display the chosen charts on the page.

```
categories = [
  { name: 'Comparisons', filter: 'comparisons', selected: false },
  { name: 'Composition', filter: 'relationships', selected: false },
  { name: 'Distribution', filter: 'distribution', selected: false },
  { name: 'Individual Metric', filter: 'individual-metric', selected: false },
  { name: 'Relationships', filter: 'relationships', selected: false }
];

subcategories = [
  { name: 'Data over Time', filter: 'data-over-time', selected: false },
  { name: 'Patterns', filter: 'patterns', selected: false },
  { name: 'Location', filter: 'location', selected: false },
  { name: 'Proportions', filter: 'proportions', selected: false }
];

selectedCategories = [];
selectedSubcategories = [];
chartsToDisplay = [];

categorySelect(category) {
  if (category.selected) {
    this.selectedCategories.push(category.filter);
  } else {
    // remove un-checked item from the array
    let toDel = this.selectedCategories.indexOf(category.filter);
    this.selectedCategories.splice(toDel, 1);
  }

  if (!this.selectedCategories.length) {
    this.subcategories.forEach(function(value, index) {
      value.selected = false;
    });
  }
}

subcategorySelect(subcategory) {
  if (subcategory.selected) {
    this.selectedSubcategories.push(subcategory.filter);
  } else {
    // remove un-checked item from the array
    let toDel = this.selectedSubcategories.indexOf(subcategory.filter);
    this.selectedSubcategories.splice(toDel, 1);
  }

}
```

I tried doing it with only the subcategories, but I'm not getting anywhere:

```
filterCharts(subcats) {
  this.displayedCharts = this.chartTypes.filter(c => c.subcategory === subcats);
}
```

Probably not important in this case, but here's the HTML I am using for testing:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let cat of categories">
    <input type="checkbox"
          [(ngModel)]="cat.selected"
          (ngModelChange)="categorySelect(cat)"> {{cat.filter}}
  </li>
</ul>

<ul *ngIf="selectedCategories.length">
  <li *ngFor="let subcat of subcategories">
    <input type="checkbox"
          [(ngModel)]="subcat.selected"
          (ngModelChange)="subcategorySelect(subcat)"> {{subcat.filter}}
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>Charts</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let chart of displayedCharts">
    {{chart.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the question and a few assumptions, i think the code will need the following ..

1. Looping through the list of charts.
2. Seeing if selectedCategories is a subset of each chart's category.
3. Seeing if selectedSubcategories is a subset of each chart's subcategory.
4. Filtering out the charts for which 3 and 4 are true.

If the list of charts is in a variables called `charts`, then

```
charts.filter(chart =>
    selectedCategories.every(c => chart.category.includes(c))
    && selectedSubcategories.every(sc => chart.subcategory.includes(sc))
)
```